# Cannot create private image as raw disk is larger than 100 Gb

Tags: google-compute-engine

I tried to create a new GoogleCloudPlatform private image by importing a raw disk file:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/import-existing-image

where the disk.raw had been created in accordance to the "building-images" tutorial.

However the disk.raw file is 160GB before tar.gz compression, so when trying to create the image I got the following error: "Creating image "xxxx" failed. Error: the size of the image inside the tar archive is larger than 100Gb."

Any sugesstions to overcome that, please ? Can you launch a GCE instance from a qcow2 file instead of a raw image ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately  disk.raw [cannot be larger](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/building-images) than 100GB. If the current image also contains data, you could try to separate the data from the OS itself. For example create the image just for the OS and the applications. Move the data to/from the VM via a GCS bucket.